# how to get email id from google api response

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

i am able to get user information from Google API response using oath2 . But i do't know how to get those responses individually .

**Response i am getting from Google Api:**
*

```
Access token: ya29.AHES6ZQ3QxKxnfAzpZasdfd23423NuxJs29gMa39MXV551yMmyM5IgA 
     {
     "id": "112361XXXXXXXXXXX",
     "name": "Ansuman XX",
     "given_name": "Ansuman",
     "family_name": "Singh",
     "link": "https://plus.google.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "gender": "male",
     "birthday": "0000-03-18",
     "locale": "en"
    }
    Original Token: ya29.AHES6ZQ3QxKxnfAzpZu0lYHYu8sdfsdafdgMa39MXV551yMmyM5IgA New Token: ya29.AHES6ZQ3QxKxnfdsfsdaYHYu8TNuxJs29gMa39MXV551yMmyM5IgA
```

**But i want only "id" & "name" indiviually to save in my Database table. How can i do this?**

I got those above response/output By using the below code.

```
             public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
          {

            -------------------------
            -------------------------
            -------------------------        

            String accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;
            GoogleAccessProtectedResource access = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken, TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authResponse.refreshToken); 
            HttpRequestFactory rf = TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(access);
            System.out.println("Access token: " + authResponse.accessToken); 
            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token="   + authResponse.accessToken;
                final StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer(); 
                    final URL u = new URL(url);
                    final URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
                    final int end = 1000;
                    InputStreamReader isr = null;
                    BufferedReader br = null; 
                        isr = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
                        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        final int chk = 0;
                        while ((url = br.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if ((chk >= 0) && ((chk < end)))
                            {
                                r.append(url).append('\n');
                            }
                         } 
              System.out.print("");
              System.out.println();
 System.out.print(" "+   r ); //this is printing at once but i want them individually
              access.refreshToken();
 System.out.println("Original Token: " + accessToken + " New Token: " + access.getAccessToken());
          }
```

Comment: 2 cents: you might want to consider not reusing the url variable in your read loop.  You're saving a minuscule bit of memory, if that's the intent, but the clarity of the code suffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you could use a JSON library like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) (designed around simplicity; examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)) on the whole resultant JSON object, or you could go with your own regex code.  something like the following might work for the latter:

```
//.... other existing code
String pat = "\"(.*)\": \"(.*)\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher matcher = null;
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

while ((url = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if ((chk >= 0) && ((chk < end))) {  
        matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
        //r.append(url).append('\n');
    }
} 
System.out.println(map.get("id"));
//... rest of code
```

The library approach might be overkill, but might handle datatype conversions, etc.  Also would have handling of non-string datatypes vs. my sad regex.

Comment: Thanks i am getting id. But how you know these things. I also want to help other people by answering their problem, like how you answered my question.